# I want to access a node from an XML which value is a string

Tags: xpath

I have an XML that has a node with an XML as it's

```
value(&lt;name&gt;  &lt;name1&gt;   &lt;name2&gt;value&lt;/name2&gt;    &lt;/name1&gt; &lt;/name&gt;),
```

The problem is that this value is an XML not converted to XML.
How can I access this value by node `name2`?

I used these two functions:

```
substring-before(string, string)
substring-after(string, string) to return what i want and it works
```

The problem is that I can't use this kind of function in the application I'm using, because it has a primitive version of XPath that doesn't accept advanced XPath.

```
<Input>
 <Response>
&lt;name&gt;    &lt;name1&gt;   &lt;name2&gt;value&lt;/name2&gt;    &lt;/name1&gt; &lt;/name&gt;
 </Response>
</Input>

<name2>value</name2>
```

Comment: You are limited to XPath-1.0, aren't you?

Comment: You want to parse a string as an XML document/fragment. There are many atempts for this in stackoverflow from the standard use of XPATH 3.0 `parse-xml()` function to adhoc and very limited "parsing" with string manipulation.

Comment: @zx485 Yes I'm limited.

Comment: @Alejandro I can't use any function

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not *well-formed* XML.
But you can pre-process the *entities* with `sed`, for example:

```
sed -e "s/&lt;/</g; s/&gt;/>/g" input.xml
```

This command changes all `&lt;` and `&gt;` entities to `<` and `>`, respectively.
After this conversion, you can apply an XML parser to your data.

Comment: The problem is that is just an application who receive an Xpath and retrieve the value that the person want. I can't parse because is just like a validator, but save the data that we retrieve to a database table.